# When using self in the completion block, does it always have a memory leak in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, automatic-ref-counting, retain-cycle

I've been working on Swift for about half a year, and now I struggle with understanding when to use the `[weak self]` to avoid a memory leak. TBH, it was too difficult for me to understand from the document or other people's articles, so I used [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=chI-B8u4MBs&ab_channel=iOSAcademy) to figure out when to use it.
I kinda understood when to use the `[weak self]` but not 100% sure its usage.

In the video, for instance, the guy created an alert controller in the view controller.

```
class TestVC: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "message", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "done", style: .cancel, handler: { _ in
            self.doSomething()
        }))
        
        present(alert, animated: true)
    }
    
    func doSomething() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

He explains that

- the view controller creates the alert
- when the done button is pressed, in the handler closure, it references self, which is a view controller.

So in the above, I get I must use `[weak self]` to deallocate the view controller.
However, now I'm confused with when not to use the `weak self`.

For instance, say I have a view controller with a function to animate the view.

```
class TestVC: UIViewController {

    let testView = TestView()
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        changeViewHeight()

    }
    
    func changeViewHeight() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 3) {
            self.testView.heightConstraint?.constant = 40
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

So in the code above, since the TestVC has a reference to changeViewHeight function, and in the completion block of the animate function, it points back to TestVC using `self`, should I change it to `[weak self]`?

Also, I think any function with a completion block has a chance to use `self` in the completion block, but that time is the retain cycle is happening and I should consider using `[weak self]` whenever I use `self` in the completion block? (which I guess it's not, but cannot explain why, so if someone can explain please let me know.)

Comment: Usually : use `[weak self]` when it's inside an instance function, and you don't need it when it's a class function. But there shouldn't be issue about writing `[weak self]` even if it's not needed.

Comment: @Larme
Thank you so much for the quick response. So, you mean the instance function `changeViewHeight` in my example code causes the memory leak and I should use `[weak self]`?
like, 
[weak self]
self?.testView.heightConstraint?.constant = 40

Comment: I meant that `UIView.animate(withDuration:completion:)` is a class method, so in theory it shouldn't capture `self`. It's known that it won't capture it, but bad implementation of class method could cause a retain, it depends on how it's implemented.

Comment: The general rule to use `[weak self]` is to when there is a chance of retain cycle meaning when two objects are owning each other. In your case, `testView` is captured by `UIView.animate` for modification but not vice versa so `weak` is not needed.

Comment: @Larme
Ahh, now I get what you mean.